# Truth table of quantifiers

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Is it possible to draw the truth table of ∃x,(P(x)∨Q(x))?
I thought of this as follows,let x be any arbitrary domain containing, x1,x2,...,xN,
So the above expression translates to (P(x1)∨Q(x1))∨(P(x2)∨Q(x2))...∨(P(xN)∨Q(xN)).
Using this can I construct a truth table?

Comment: It's possible, but what would you do if the $x_i$ come from an infinite domain?

Answer (score 4):

Only if the domain of intepretation is *finite*.

But a predicate formula is *valid* if it is true in **all** interpretations, and thus we have to take into account also intepretation with *infinite* domain, like $\mathbb N$.

For example, the formula $\exists y \forall x (x \le y)$ is *true* in every *finite* domain of natural numbers, but it is clearly false in $\mathbb N$.